# Python compare two files using a list

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, loops

Im trying to compare two files via regex strings and print the output. I seem to have an issue with my loop as only the last line gets printed out. What am I missing ?

```
 import re
 delist = [r'"age":.*",',r'"average":.*",',r'"class":.*",']
 with open('test1.txt', 'r') as bolo:
    boloman = bolo.read()
 for dabo in delist:
    venga = re.findall(dabo, boloman)
    for vaga in venga:
    with open ('test.txt', 'r' ) as f:
       content = f.read()
       venga2 = re.findall(dabo, content)
       for vaga2 in venga2:
          mboa = content.replace(vaga2,vaga,1)

  print (mboa)
```

Comment: I am not so sure but I think the line "mboa = content.replace(vaga2,vaga,1)" is causing the error because it replacing stuff in mboa. So it takes out everything but the last line ??

Answer (score 0):

At first, a problem I see is that you are always setting mboa with the only result. I think what you really want to do is to create a list and append it to that list.

```
import re

mboa = []
delist = [r'"age":.*",',r'"average":.*",',r'"class":.*",']
with open('test1.txt', 'r') as bolo:
  boloman = bolo.read()
  for dabo in delist:
    venga = re.findall(dabo, boloman)
    for vaga in venga:
      with open ('test.txt', 'r' ) as f:
        content = f.read()
        venga2 = re.findall(dabo, content)
        for vaga2 in venga2:
          mboa.append(content.replace(vaga2,vaga,1))
print (mboa)
```

does that solve the issue? if it doesn't add a comment to this question and I'll try to fix it out ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help. The list approach you gave added \n and gave out multiple prints.

Comment: alright, did the print have the expected result? you want to show it in a specific format?